# Can you mix HTML and XAML in a windows 8 Metro App?

Tags: html, xaml, microsoft-metro

Is there anyway to mix HTML UI and XAML UI in a windows 8 Metro App?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe no, **XAML** and **HTML/CSS** are separate paths when it comes to presentation layer and you can't mix them (except for the 'dirty tricks' like *WebView* control in XAML, but it's no use for component reusability).

The [Windows 8 architecture diagram](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/ctodx/Windows8Architecture_485458D4.png) might be useful to see how XAML/HTML/WinRT are they related. Apps in HTML/JS are rendered in Internet Explorer 10 Metro, just in another context (with extended APIs , different security rules etc), while XAML has different mechanisms. WinRT is deep below the presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. HTML stands on its own with CSS and Javascript.
Why do you need to do this?
I believe with HTML5, you would not need XAML.

Comment: well obviously you can do some stuff that aren't part of the HTML/JS standard, but calling the WinRT apis including C# or C++ libraries you can wrapped. the reason i ask is more of code reuse. if i made a XAML based control that had some good functionality and want to use it in aq variety of metro apps, some made in XAML , some with HTML

Comment: Yes, you can write a WinRT DLL and write reusable components to be used from JS. But when it comes to UI, I don't think you can place a XAML UI element in HTML.